# Drawing a triangle on top of a circle in OpenGL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

I'm trying to draw a triangle with it's top point in the middle of a circle. Unfortunately I keep getting an error in visual studio, 0x80070003. It still shows the triangle I have drawn but it doesn't show the circle. I'd really appreciate any help I could get. I am using GLEW and GLFW as well.

I've tried to create multiple VAO's to store two different VBO's and then draw them separately, but that didn't worked.

```
#define PI 3.14159265
#define MAX_SLICES 32
#define MIN_SLICES 8
#define MAX_VERTICES (MAX_SLICES+2)*3
#define CIRCLE_RADIUS 0.5
#define WINDOW_WIDTH 1280
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT 720


GLfloat c_vertices[MAX_VERTICES] = {
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
};

GLfloat t_vertices[] = {
    0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
   -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f
};

GLuint c_slices = MIN_SLICES;   // number of circle slices

GLuint g_VBO[2];            // vertex buffer object identifier
GLuint g_VAO[2];            // vertex array object identifier
GLuint g_shaderProgramID = 0;       // shader program identifier

void generate_circle()
{
    float slice_angle = PI * 2 / static_cast<float>(c_slices);  // angle for each fan slice
    float angle = slice_angle;                                  // angle used to generate x and y coordinates
    float scale_factor = static_cast<float>(WINDOW_HEIGHT) / WINDOW_WIDTH;  // scale to make it a circle instead of an elipse
    int index = 0;  // vertex index

    c_vertices[3] = CIRCLE_RADIUS * scale_factor;   // set x coordinate of vertex 1

    // generate vertex coordinates for triangle fan
    for (int i = 2; i < c_slices + 2; i++)
    {
           // multiply by 3 because a vertex has x, y, z coordinates
           index = i * 3;

           c_vertices[index] = CIRCLE_RADIUS * cos(angle) * scale_factor;
           c_vertices[index + 1] = CIRCLE_RADIUS * sin(angle);
           c_vertices[index + 2] = 0.0f;

           // update to next angle
           angle += slice_angle
     }
}

static void init()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);   // set clear background colour

    // create and compile our GLSL program from the shader files
    g_shaderProgramID = loadShaders("SimpleVS.vert", "SimpleFS.frag");

    // create VBO and buffer the data
    glGenBuffers(2, g_VBO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(t_vertices), t_vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*3*(c_slices + 2), c_vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    // create VAO and specify VBO data
    glGenVertexArrays(2, g_VAO);

    glBindVertexArray(g_VAO[0]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO[0]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);  // specify the form of the data

    glBindVertexArray(g_VAO[1]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO[1]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);   // enable vertex attributes
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
}

static void render_scene()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   // clear colour buffer

    glUseProgram(g_shaderProgramID);    // use the shaders associated with the shader program

    glBindVertexArray(g_VAO[0]);            // make VAO active
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);   // display the vertices based on the primitive type

    glBindVertexArray(g_VAO[1]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, c_slices + 2);

    glFlush();  // flush the pipeline
}
```

Comment: If a vertex attribute is enabled or disabled is stored in the VAO. glEnableVertexAttribArray has to be called for each VAO separately. The program should show the circle rather than the triangle.